# Razor with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
 @if (Model.PaymentMethodTypeId == (int) PaymentMethodType.PayPal)
 {
     var url = @MyLibraryHtml.JavascriptEncodeUrl(Url.RewriteAction("SaveNewPaymentMethod", "PaymentMethods"));
     var args = form.serialize();
     @Html.Raw(" var url = ")
 }
```

Inside if block the code is Javascript, but as I expected, Razor see var url and var arg as .NET variable.

I know I can use Html.Raw but is there any other better solution for this problem, Because I believe that Html.Raw breaks readibility

Comment: I'm not sure if such mix of js and c# is good solution. I think it is better to initialize some js var form c# and then do cndition in js or use data- attribute to pass data to js. Genarally keep js separed from c#(razor) code. Anyone agree?

Comment: @py3r3str actually you are right because this is a business logic and it must be done at controller, however I am updating this code and it was just like before, so I dont have chance to change the way that I am doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<text></text>` element to tell Razor that the code inside the `if` should be treated as "text" instead of c# code:

```
@if (Model.PaymentMethodTypeId == (int) PaymentMethodType.PayPal)
 {
     <text>
     var url = @MyLibraryHtml.JavascriptEncodeUrl(Url.RewriteAction("SaveNewPaymentMethod", "PaymentMethods"));
     var args = form.serialize();
     </text>
 }
```

Alternatively if you only have a few lines you can use the `@:` to "escape" single lines:

```
@if (Model.PaymentMethodTypeId == (int) PaymentMethodType.PayPal)
 {
     @:var url = @MyLibraryHtml.JavascriptEncodeUrl(Url.RewriteAction("SaveNewPaymentMethod", "PaymentMethods"));
     @:var args = form.serialize();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, <text> seems the best

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the contents of the block in `<text>` tags to force Razor to treat it as markup rather than server-side code.

However, writing server-generated Javascript code is generally a bad idea; it's rather unreadable and is very easy to make XSS holes.

Instead, you should store the server-side code in `data-` attributes, and read them in normal JS code.